# Is Rod cutting Algorithm a Semi-Greedy Algorithm

Tags: algorithm

In My example 7 Inch Long Rod can be divided into 6 + 1 or in 2 + 2 + 3 manner.
Now assume if my algorithm chooses First partition.

```
6 + 1
```

instead of

```
2 + 2 + 3
```

Should i say it is a Semi-Greedy Approach, As i know Rod Cutting Problem is a Dynamic Programming Problem

Comment: Are the two solutions equivalent in cost?

Comment: Oh, I am sorry for that, Yes both partitions have same price

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is **no such term** like semi greedy algorithm, okay.

 It chooses first choice because it search for  more price and if it terminates, it doesn't go for another option, it is all because of `<=` expression; which compares optimality of rod cutting combination, not because it is a semi greedy algorithm.

I beleive it is now clear to you

Answer (score 0):

**A Greedy Algorithm**

> Semi-Greedy Approach

A Greedy algorithm is some algorithm that attempts to solve the whole problem, by dividing it up into sub problems, and attempting to choose the optimum solution for those problems, in the context of the sub problem. This can often lead to a solution, but not to a global optimum solution. Semi-Greedy doesn't make any sense. It either is or it isn't.

**The Rod Cutting Problem**

The Rod cutting problem is the most efficient way to cut a Rod, based on a table of values that inform how much it *costs* to cut the rod.

**Your algorithm as it is**

Well.. I don't see the value to *be greedy* about. If we're trying to split it up into as few numbers as possible, then obviously you'll be greedy on the largest number that is less than the number to split.

A greedy algorithm requires some goal to work towards. Simply splitting up a "rod" doesn't have implied value.

**Your algorithm if we have a cost matrix**

If you had a cost matrix, and your algorithm attempted to cut using the cheapest values, then it would be a greedy algorithm, because you're being greedy on cost.

Comment: "A Greedy algorithm ... by dividing it up into sub problems, and attempting to choose the optimum solution for those problems" - I like the The [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_algorithm) wording, which emphasises that it's about making *locally* optimal choices. My informal version - grab what looks best now without anticipating the consequences. On seeing OPs question, I wondered if there was a "grab what looks good now, without confirming it's even locally best" variant. Even cases where selecting locally-second-best tends to be better in the long run. I guess not.

Comment: By choosing the least costly option during each stage, it is a greedy algorithm. Granted, not a very good one.